# go error plugin when running heroku login on windows 10

Tags: powershell, heroku, windows-10, heroku-cli

I just downloaded and updated Heroku, and then ran

```
> heroku login
```

in my PowerShell, but got the following error:

```
(node:1496) [UNKNOWN] Error Plugin: heroku: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'U:\_netrc'
Error occurred during reading netrc file: U:\_netrc
module: @oclif/config@1.13.2
task: runHook prerun
plugin: heroku
root: C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\heroku\client\7.59.2
See more details with DEBUG=*
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'U:/_netrc'
```

I couldn't find much information about the error message, and would appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `U:` drive? Any idea why it might be seen as your home directory? Can you write to that location?

Comment: I figured it out! So I'm using a university computer from home. After I connect to the VPN, I got access to the U drive and the command worked fine.